# Regex matching on certain character, that is NOT sorrounded by two specific character, that are excluded from match

Tags: regex

I have what I feel is quite an annoying case.

I have some json, where I need to remove all occurences of a single backslash, but whenever I have two or more backshlashes next to each other, I would like to keep them there

So for the following example:

```
{\"status\": "hi <a href=\\\"url.com\\\" \"
```

I want to remove the three occurences of a single backslash, but not touch the two places where there are three backslashes next to each other.

So, using the visual studio code ctrl+H regex function, I came up with this regex, where I match on all backslashes that do not have a backslash next to them, like so:

```
[^\\]\\[^\\]
```

and this rightly grabs the single backslashes, but, it also matches on the character to the left, and right to the backslash. Which means it matches on:

```
{\"
```

So, can I somehow to this same pattern, but excluding the two characters adjacent to the backslash from the match?

best regards

Comment: Regex is not the right tool to parse JSON

Comment: but if I have a json string and just want to have a look at it, and browse it in a editor such as vscode

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `negative lookbehind` and `negative lookahead` to achieve this.

```
/(?<!\\)\\(?!\\)/g
```

`(?<!\\)` means only if there doesn't exist a `\` before this point.

`(?!\\)` means that there shouldn't be a `\` after this point.

You can try it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/siZhTq/1).